# how to paste text to a Form's RichTextBox from another Form's Thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a windows form application in C#.Where i have a RichTextBox(Txt) in the Main window(MainForm) and a public method

```
public void postTxt(String txt)
{
    //do some database update
    this.Txt.AppendText(txt);
}
```

I have another Form called SerialTranseiver(MainForm mn) which is passed the MainForm as a parameter in the constructor.

```
SerialTranseiver(MainForm mn)
{
    //-----other codes
    this.tmpMain=mn;
}
```

This second class has a SerialPort(Sport) and waits for data and whenever data found in its
SerialDataReceivedEventHandler calls mn.postTxt(Sport.ReadLine().toString())

```
void Sport_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    mn.postTxt(Sport.ReadLine().toString());
    //---database updating codes and other stuff
 }
```

this causes an exception that says

```
Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'Txt' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on
```

How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to invoke a delegate asyncronously which is made public in the form you invoke it on. For example:

```
 mainForm.BeginInvoke(mainForm.logDelegate,destination,fileName,bytesSent, true);
```

I'd suggest you reading [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a06c0dc2.aspx) first and [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/begininvoke.aspx) afterwards

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem just read this posts:

- [Control.InvokeRequired Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired.aspx)
- [Control.Invoke Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx)

For your case, try this:

```
void Sport_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired) 
    {
        this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => Sport_DataReceived(sender, e)));
        return;
    }

    mn.postTxt(Sport.ReadLine().toString());
    //---database updating codes and other stuff
}
```